# Java calculation method is returning 1.0 instead of 0.5? What do?

Tags: java, arrays, formula

When testing this code with Max 70 and Min 59 it returns 1.0 instead of 0.5. Is my formula wrong? Also the 2nd if statement is for these directions: (public static double hdd(int max, int min) that returns the HDD for a single day. If either max 
or min is -999 (missing) return 0.0. If max < min return 0.0.) So idk if relevant to the problem.

```
/**
 * Calculate heating degree day.
 * @param max The highest temperature for a given day.
 * @param min The lowest temperature for a given day.
 * @return heating degree day data for this day.
 */
public static double hdd(int max, int min)
{
    double average = (max + min) / 2;
    double hdd = 0.0;

    if (average < 65.0)
    {
        hdd = 65.0 - average;
    }
    else
    {
        hdd = 0.0;
    }

    if(max == -999 || min == -999)
    {
        hdd = 0.0;
    }
    else if (max < min)
    {
       hdd = 0.0;   
    }


    return hdd;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that `(max + min) / 2` is an integer division, which means it gets truncated to the integer below.  In this case, `(70 + 59) / 2` gives `64`, which you are then storing in a `double`.  But that won't restore the missing `0.5`.

You need to convert either the numerator or the denominator to a `double` before dividing.  Writing `2.0` in place of `2` is one way to achieve this.

Comment: Ah Thank you so much. So just like chathux suggestion, I should divide by 2.0 since it's a double value.

Comment: Yes, chathux's answer is correct.  An `int` divided by a `double` gives a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

when you divide an integer by another integer the result will be also an integer. so it will not have a fractional part.

you can fix this by changing this line

`double average = (max + min) / 2;`

to this

`double average = (max + min) / 2.0;`